# How to show to id of the selected item in combo box when changing it?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have problem in my combo box. I want to show the `id` of the `property_name` in `label1` when changing the items in combo box.

```
Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = exec("SELECT id,property_name FROM tbl_property")

    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

            prop.Items.Add(dt.Rows(x).Item(1).ToString)
            Label1.Text = dt.Rows(x).Item(0).ToString
        Next

    End If
```

This is my code. I want to show in the `label1` the id of the items in the combo box. but the output in `label1` is the last id in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You should be populating your `DataTable` with the `id` and property name in the first place, then binding that `DataTable` to the `ComboBox` and the `Label`. The `Label` will then update automatically when the user makes a selection in the `ComboBox`.

```cs
Dim table = Exec("SELECT id, property_name FROM tbl_property")

myBindingSource.DataSource = table

With myComboBox
    .DisplayMember = "property_name"
    .ValueMember = "id"
    .DataSource = myBindingSource
End With

myLabel.DataBindings.Add(NameOf(myLabel.Text), myBindingSource, "id")
```

You don't have to use a `BindingSource` but you should. You can add one to the form in the designer.

With regards to what you're doing in the code you posted, there's no use setting the `Text` of the `Label` in that loop because that's just going to display the `id` from the last record and then nothing else will happen when the user changes the selection.